# better search algorithm to increase the performance?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, search

I have list of students displaying in a page and I am storing the student information as object with id and name.

I want to add search box to search students if I got a scroll bar in the list.

And update the students list according to the search string.

Right now i am iterating student object array and checking the index of the search string in the name.

Is there any better algorithm to increase the performance.

// my code:

search = function(data,queryString)
{
   var res = new array();
      for(stu in data){
           if(stu.name.search(queryString) != -1){
                 res.push(stu);
           }
      }
   return res;
}

Comment: Show us your current code. Unless there are literally thousands of students in this list, this should be quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a sorted index and use binary search. Multiple indices if you need to search by multiple criteria, e.g. name or ID. Simpler to implement than a tree.

Comment: some student may add after creating a sorted index

Comment: The index will have to be updated if new students are inserted, of course. Otherwise it's no good.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look for a trie-datastructure or a radix-trie or a crit-bit trie where empty nodes are compressed. You want to look for a kart-trie a special version of the radix-trie where there is only 2 edges in a node. In general a trie is good for text search algorithm, for example a dictionary. I have done an implementation of the kart-trie in php at phpclasses.org ( kart-trie ). You are welcome to download and play with it.