# How do I match an input to an array index?

Tags: c

For this program I want to get an input from the user for a TV channel, which would be

```
int tv[] = {2, 4, 5, 6, 8};
```

and I want to prompt the user to input the TV channel they want so `scanf` for tv channel 4 which would be array `index [1]`. How do I match the scanned tv channel (4) to a new variable which would equal the array index of [1]?

Comment: Are you speaking of something like using Enumeration ?

Comment: It seems you want to use associative array.

Answer (score 2):

Read the channel number from the user, and loop through the array to find the place where that channel number is.

Answer (score 1):

Do a simple linear search, where element ( channel number here) is sequentially searched in the array

```
int channelnumber,arrayindex;
printf("\n Enter the channel number");
scanf("%d",&channelnumber)
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
     if(tv[i]==channelnumber)
     {
        arrayindex=i;
        break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question is a simple case of searching. You can probably do a linear search if the channels are not in order or else make use of binary search logic for finding the channel. If you dont want that either then make use of hashing concept. But that will increase the size of the array but it help u to find the element very easily.

Hope that answers to your question.....

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to search the array through using some [searching algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500579/better-search-algorithm-to-increase-the-performance). If your array is **HUGE**, then you may want to look at a c++ container called as [**map**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/). If you create a map, then you can do the association you mentioned in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Searching every time in an array could be expensive(in my opinion if you have a large array) one other solution could be that you can have another array which would map you to the right index

for example,

```
int tv[] = {2, 4, 5, 6, 8};
int mapping[]={-1,-1,0,-1,1,2,3,-1,-1,4};
tv[mapping[channelNumber]]//getting the actual value
```

this would take additional space but can give you performance improvment